# How to validated that an object contains only alphabet characters with DataAnnotation?

Tags: c#, string, data-annotations, system.componentmodel

I am writing some code validating that the user has submitted an object with the correct information. In other words, how would I validate that the name contains no numbers, signs, and other notation except from the English alphabet or latin foreign vowels (french, german, etc)?

```
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [DataType()] //I think a solution would use custom datatypes
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\p{L}]+$")]
```

This basically says "only allow any Unicode character in the entire thing".

Comment: I would like the user to enter a name like this "bob" but not this "bob1$+". Thx for the answer but how would i do that?

Comment: The above will do that. $ ^ and + have special meanings in regular expressions. Try it and see.

Comment: and how would I allow spaces?